# Django model filter compare month fail

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have this model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Here is one of the records in database,

```
id=15,
username='yhbohh'
last_login='2015-03-31 10:57:18'
```

I would like to get a number count of objects with last login of month=3.

I tried in shell,

```
User.objects.filter(last_login__year=2015).count() # return 80
User.objects.filter(last_login__month=3).count() # return 0
User.objects.filter(last_login__day=31).count() # return 0
```

May I know why the last 2 queries return no records?
I have searched from the other questions and notice than someone may suggest to use date range comparison to solve this problem. But I just wanna know the root cause of this unexpected result.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have `USE_TZ = True` in your _settings.py_?

Comment: @soon, yes i saw it in settings.py

Comment: The documentation [says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#month), that all datetime objects are converted to current timezone before filtering. May this cause the problem you are facing with?

Comment: Oh yes, it works now but I need to investigate to see if this setting will cause impact to any part of my project. Thanks a lot for your solution @soon, and you can post it as an answer for my acceptance. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#month):

> When `USE_TZ` is `True`, datetime fields are converted to the current time
>   zone before filtering.